# Calculating ordered occurance # in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset which includes:

1. guest id (guest)
2. Date of stay (checkInDate)
3. 100s of other variables I'd rather leave untouched

I've been calculating the number of total stays a guest has had with the following:

`data <- ddply(data, .(guest), transform, Stays = length(guest))`

However, I'd like to calculate *which* stay each is. Ie "1" for 1st stay, "5" for 5th stay, etc, rather than just labeling all of the guest's stays as "5".

I'm guessing that the solution will likely involve some form of ordering by guest and then by checkInDate, but I'm not sure how to implement this.

```
checkInDate     guest          currentsolution    desiredsolution
2020-02-01      longstring1    3                  1
2020-03-01      longstring1    3                  2
2020-04-01      longstring1    3                  3
2020-02-01      longstring2    2                  1
2020-03-01      longstring2    2                  2
2020-02-01      longstring3    1                  1
2019-02-01      longstring4    1                  1
```

Comment: @akrun I've added this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `plyr`, we can use `seq_along` instead of `length`

```
library(plyr)
data <- data[order(data$guest, as.Date(data$checkInDate)),]
ddply(data, .(guest), transform, Stays = seq_along(guest))
#   checkInDate       guest Stays
#1  2020-02-01 longstring1     1
#2  2020-03-01 longstring1     2
#3  2020-04-01 longstring1     3
#4  2020-02-01 longstring2     1
#5  2020-03-01 longstring2     2
#6  2020-02-01 longstring3     1
#7  2019-02-01 longstring4     1
```

We can use `row_number()`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(guest) %>%
     mutate(Stays = row_number(as.Date(checkInDate)))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
# Groups:   guest [4]
#  checkInDate guest       Stays
#  <chr>       <chr>       <int>
#1 2020-02-01  longstring1     1
#2 2020-03-01  longstring1     2
#3 2020-04-01  longstring1     3
#4 2020-02-01  longstring2     1
#5 2020-03-01  longstring2     2
#6 2020-02-01  longstring3     1
#7 2019-02-01  longstring4     1
```

---

Or with `rowid`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[order(as.IDate(checkInDate)), Stays := rowid(guest)]
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(checkInDate = c("2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-04-01", 
"2020-02-01", "2020-03-01", "2020-02-01", "2019-02-01"), guest = c("longstring1", 
"longstring1", "longstring1", "longstring2", "longstring2", "longstring3", 
"longstring4")), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I should have added that the data _isn't_ sorted by anything at the moment, so I'm not sure method one or two works.

For the rowid method, I get "Error in as.IDate(checkInDate) : object 'checkInDate' not found" despite data$checkInDate being a thing.

Comment: @Adam Yes, that is the reason i used `row_number` with `as.Date(checkInDate)` to order

Comment: @Adam sorry the error is because I forgot to add `setDT` to convert to data.table.  Updated

Comment: @Adam Updated the `plyr` method. as well

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [order](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/order) function:

```
library(plyr)

data <- data.frame(
  guest = sample(1:10, 100, replace = T)
)

ddply(data, .(guest), transform, Stays = order(guest))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `match` and `unique` to get `stays` count.

```
library(dplyr)

data %>% 
   group_by(guest) %>% 
   mutate(stays = match(checkInDate, unique(checkInDate)))

#  checkInDate guest       stays
#  <chr>       <chr>       <int>
#1 2020-02-01  longstring1     1
#2 2020-03-01  longstring1     2
#3 2020-04-01  longstring1     3
#4 2020-02-01  longstring2     1
#5 2020-03-01  longstring2     2
#6 2020-02-01  longstring3     1
#7 2019-02-01  longstring4     1
```

In base R :

```
data$stays <- with(data, ave(checkInDate, guest, FUN = function(x) 
                             match(x, unique(x))))
```

Or in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, stays := match(checkInDate, unique(checkInDate)), guest]
```

---

Another approach is to convert the `factor` to integer

```
data %>% group_by(guest) %>% mutate(stays = as.integer(factor(checkInDate)))
```

Base R :

```
data$stays <- with(data, ave(checkInDate, guest, FUN = function(x) 
                             as.integer(factor(x))))
```

`data.table` :

```
setDT(data)[, stays := as.integer(factor(checkInDate)), guest]
```